# How to execute 3 lines at same time?

Tags: excel, vba, parallel-processing, execute, sap-gui

I have this code that connects to SAP GUI. These three lines are connected to the buttons to run in 3 different windows of SAP. But each window takes about 15 minutes to load. I need the three buttons to run at the same time or not to wait for the previous one to finish so that the 3 windows can be executed at the same time and instead of taking 45 minutes, it takes 15 minutes.

Now try putting the three commands on the same line separating them by "," "&" ";" ":".

Also try to call the 3 macros at the same time.

Button 1 of windows 1

```
session1.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 8
```

Button 2 of windows 2

```
session2.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 8
```

Button 3 of windows 3

```
session3.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 8
```

First try of execute three lines at same time, but do not execute the code

```
session1.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 8, session2.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 8, session3.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 8
```

Comment: This may sound weird but SAP GUI Scripting can't automate several SAP GUI windows in parallel (although a user can manually do it without any problem), it works synchronously.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this in VBA as it runs on a single thread. Every command is executed sequentially and has to wait for the previous one to finish.

You could write a macro to create three separate VBScripts and then run those three scripts simultaneously in order to "mimic" three threads.